# Quais as vantagens de fornecer metadados ao inserir objeto na AWS S3?

Tags: php, amazon-aws

No [AWS SDK para PHP v3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html) o método [putObject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putobject) recebe diversos parâmetros, como ContentType, ContentEncoding, etc.

[Na sua forma mais simples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html), posso inserir um objeto apenas informando `Bucket`, `Key` e `SourceFile`.

```
$result = $s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'       => $bucket,
    'Key'          => $keyname,
    'SourceFile'   => $filepath
));
```

Levando em consideração que eu vou inserir fotos e que elas devem ficar no s3 até que eu queira exclui-las, quais as vantagens/desvantagens de eu passar também metadados como `ContentType`, `ContentEncoding` entre outros?

No formato mais simples, passando apenas `Bucket`, `Key` e `SourceFile` ja vai atender o meu caso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando metadados você pode armazenar outras informações com a imagem, como o dono, data de inserção, aplicação utilizavel, ou qualquer outra informação que possa ser util para aplicação obter junto do arquivo em si. Além disso, alguns metadados são mapeados para cabeçalhos HTTP, como ContentType, Encoding, Cache Control, etc...